# Cannot reset a throttle

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel 8 on my site I'm using Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter to define my custom throttle example is

```
RateLimiter::for('stop', function (Request $request) {
            $ip = $request->ip();
            $maxAttempts = 5;
            
            $limit = Limit::perMinutes((60 * 24), $maxAttempts)->by('stop_'.$ip);
            return $limit;
        });
```

I want to clear this limit so I use

```
app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->clear('stop_'.$request->ip());
```

and also this code

```
app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->resetAttempts('stop_'.$request->ip());
```

but none of this would work after reloading the page is still showing the 429 error I want clear the limit on certain conditions but I can't seem to make this work how can I clear the limit without waiting for the timer? I'd like to set it to 24hrs but should able to allow users to reset it when properly validated.

Answer (score 0):

I made a digging into the code and found that the key is getting hashed before its stored on the cache but when directly sending out the clear method the hashing is not included on it so the clear should be something:

```
app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->clear(md5(<limiterName><key>));
```

for my code it should be

```
app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->clear(md5('stopstop_'.$request->ip()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->clear(md5('stopstop_'.$request->ip()));
```

OR

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;

RateLimiter::class->clear(md5('stopstop_'.$request->ip()));
```

Comment: Hi Rizalvin, welcome to SO! Could you clarify why this works as opposed what the Christopher has tried? A good answer consists of both an explaination and an example and/or a reference to documentation.